# Localising Facebook Login using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, localization, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to localise the pop-up login box shown using FB.login() under the Javascript SDK but the dialog only displays in English.  I use the code below to connect:

```
var facebookScript = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js"
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript(facebookScript, function () {
   FB.init({
        appId: SOCIAL_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function () {
        // At some point here FB.login() is called.
    }, true);
});
```

I notice that if I take the URL of the login box and add `&locale=fr_FR` to it I get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook will automatically use the appropriate locale based on information from the users browser and account.

The localized versions of the SDK is mostly to make a few adaptions that need to happen on the third party site, mostly around left-to-right/right-to-left languages, and some labels.

Comment: I didn't get around to answering this before but this certainly works in practice, however mystifying it is that you can access different localisations of the connect scripts.

Comment: Edited to add some context about the localized resources.